# Calculating possibilities PHP, MySqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of 6 numbers with the day.

```
1   5   8   14  35  45  Mon
13  26  30  31  43  49  Sat
1   4   13  19  34  39  Wed
2   20  21  24  25  43  Mon
1   6   31  33  39  45  Sat
2   11  16  21  25  28  Wed
17  21  24  37  46  48  Mon
6   10  11  22  28  33  Sat
3   10  23  30  38  45  Wed
```

I'm trying to create a script that will give me the most 6 numbers repeated for that day.

This script below will give my all numbers that are repeated for the first column.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect_db,"SELECT first, COUNT(first) AS ct
FROM numbers
GROUP BY first
ORDER BY first DESC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<table class="first"><tr><td>'. $row[1].'</td><tr></table>';

        }
```

but I need only 6 numbers with the highest repetitive occurrence.

The DB :
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the lottery results? :-P

Comment: something similar...

Comment: Your query doesn't group by day? You only test the first number not all numbers for that day?

Comment: can't figure out how to do it for all columns in a single query...

Comment: can you give an example of the expected output, would help me come up with a solution.

Comment: the output would be 3,5,6,9,10,11,Mon where the numbers would be the numbers with the highest occurrence for that day.

Comment: how do you get 3? 1 appears 3 times and 3 only 1....

Comment: need expected output with the given table

Comment: the numbers are made up...

Comment: The numbers can be made up but the expected output has to match the example you gave to be at all useful in telling us what you're actually trying to do. Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand the question now. Try this.

```
$numLabels = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth');

$numbers= array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM numbers";
$rows = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if ($rows) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {

        //indexing all the numbers and counting occurrences
        foreach ($numLabels as $label) {
            if (isset($numbers[$row['day']][$row[$label]])) {
                $numbers[$row['day']][$row[$label]] ++;
            } else {
                $numbers[$row['day']][$row[$label]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_free_result($rows);

    //sorting by occurrences
    foreach (array_keys($numbers) as $key) {
        arsort($numbers[$key]);
    }

    //getting the most common 6
    foreach ($numbers as $day => $dayNumbers) {
        $numbers[$day] = array_slice(array_keys($dayNumbers), 0, 6);
    }
}

//example output format: "Day: num1-num2-num3..."
foreach ($numbers as $day => $dayNumbers) {
    echo $day . ': ' . implode('-', $dayNumbers) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: this is not giving me the most occurred numbers

Comment: I think it should. Are you sure?

Comment: You are right, it works! Do you know how I change var_dump into readable array?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to access results.

Comment: there is actually a problem, I got Mon: 2-6-28-37-37-47 which is not right. It can't be 37 twice. I should get the most occurring 6 numbers for Monday.

Comment: You can access the individual numbers like this: $numbers['Mon'][0], $numbers['Mon'][1], ...

Answer (score 0):

You're using six columns to represent what is essentially a single attribute; that's why your desired result is so awkward to achieve. The query would be *much* simpler if your table was normalized. Here's one possible table design that's *more normalized* than your current table:

```
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
| id  | number | position | day |
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
| 1   | 1      | 1        | Mon |
| 1   | 5      | 2        | Mon |
| 1   | 8      | 3        | Mon |
| 1   | 14     | 4        | Mon |
| 1   | 35     | 5        | Mon |
| 1   | 45     | 6        | Mon |
| 2   | 13     | 1        | Sat |
| 2   | 26     | 2        | Sat |
| 2   | 30     | 3        | Sat |
| 2   | 31     | 4        | Sat |
| ... | ...    | ...      | ... |
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
```

With this table, sorting the numbers by frequency on each day is simple:

```
SELECT
  day,
  number,
  COUNT(number) AS count
FROM
  table
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC;
```

For an in-depth discussion of limiting the results within each group in the above query, you could read [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). The `UNION` method is probably the best option given that you appear to only have three possible values of `day` to group on (and at most seven in any case):

```
(SELECT number, day FROM table WHERE day='Mon'
 GROUP BY day ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT number, day FROM table WHERE day='Wed'
 GROUP BY day ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT number, day FROM table WHERE day='Sat'
 GROUP BY day ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC LIMIT 6)
```

You would want a compound index on `(day, number)` for best performance. With this solution, you would avoid the overhead of transferring the entire table from the database into your PHP script. This becomes more and more important as the table grows in size. `SELECT * FROM table` is a pretty strong code smell.

There are other ways to design a normalized table to store this sort of data; for example, I'd prefer to store the calendar date and derive the day of the week from that instead of storing just the day of the week's abbreviation. But the major thing is to get your numbers into a single attribute so you can treat them like the homogeneous data they are.